# PopupWindow.showAtLocation(View parent, int gravity, int x, int y) is not showing at specified location with GridView

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridview, android-popupwindow

I'm facing an issue with `popupWindow.showAtLocation(View parent, int gravity, int x, int y)` here x-axis is working properly but it doesn't move on y-axis. Popup window is still showing on top of activity, but it finely locating at left or right location.I'm using `GridView` as a parent view, I think there is some issue with GridView but I don't know what's that issue & how to solve it.
Please somebody help me.

below is my code:

```
final GridView gridView = (GridView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_window, null, false);
gridView.setNumColumns(5);
gridView.setVerticalSpacing(50);

PopupAdapter adapter = new PopupAdapter(this, iconIds, subjectNames);
gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

popupWindow = new PopupWindow(gridView, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, false);

findViewById(R.id.open_popup_btn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        if(!popupWindow.isShowing()) {
            popupWindow.showAtLocation(gridView, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 100, 400);
        }
        else
            popupWindow.dismiss();
    }
});
```

and below is my code for **popup_window.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/grid_view">

</GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just checked your code and the popup moves along y-axis.Just to let you know to make it look uniform across all screens you should use the following method.

```
popupWindow.showAtLocation(gridView, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY,convertDpToPx(100), convertDpToPx(400));


private int convertDpToPx(int dp){
    return   (int) (dp * Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density);
}
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thanks but it's not help me. Just x value converted to pixels but y is not working, still same problem.